# Site Navigation With Sub-nav No Fixed Width

Tags: html, css

I have built a site nav with sub-navigation. The sub nav has a min-width set on it so that it can be wider than its parent element. It really needs that min-width. Otherwise, it will want to size itself relative to its parent.

My client wants the sub nav to be able to have a variable width so the sublinks don't wrap (within reason).

Ideally, the sub nav would have a min-width set on it but be able to go wider than the min-width to accommodate longer text.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

This is what I would like it to look like:
[image]

I've got my code up on Codepen here: https://codepen.io/sibarad/pen/gORqevp?editors=1100

Here's some basic code to give you an idea of the structure:

HTML:

```
<!-- Site Nav -->
<ul class="site-menu header-container--nav-mobile">
   <!-- Main Nav Item 1 -->
   <li class="site-menu__item site-menu__item--has-submenu">
      <button tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false">Nav Link 1</button>
           
      <!-- Main Nav Item 1 Sub-item -->
      <ul class="site-menu__submenu" id="dt_nav-accountbilling">
         <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav With Some Long Text That I Don't Want To Wrap</a></li>
         <li class="site-menu__subitem"><a href="#">Subnav</a></li>
      </ul><!-- /Main Nav Item 1 Sub-item -->
   </li><!-- /Main Nav Item 1 -->
```

CSS:

```
.site-menu__item {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom: 16px;
   width: 100%;
}

.site-menu__submenu {
   font-size: 14px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   left: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
   min-width: 302px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   border-radius: 0;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
   visibility: hidden;
   padding-top: 16px;
   padding-bottom: 8px;
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example image of what you want to achieve? As I read this, I think you want to display al sub items next to each other?

Comment: I updated it with another pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` on `.site-menu__item` to prevent line wrapping on your sub menu items.

#### Update

If you have no control over the length of the `.site-menu__item` link text then instead of using `white-space: nowrap`, set a width value on the `.site-menu__submenu` container to `width: max-content`. This will horizontally autofit the container to the dynamic content. Finally, add a  `max-width` to ensure your 'within reason' constraint is met.

See the example below with 768px max-width. More info on `max-content` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content).

```
.site-menu__submenu {
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 768px;
}
```

Also see updated [Pen](https://codepen.io/ositanathan/pen/RwZQRKp).

Comment: This would work but it's not very flexible. If the client adds a huge amount of text it has to wrap at some point. white-space: nowrap would never wrap.

Comment: @xoam I have updated the answer with a more flexible approach.

Comment: sorry for the delay. This is a great answer I had never learned about max-content. Very good to know for the future. Thank you!